# Programmatically converting Adobe image files to jpg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, jpeg, vector-graphics

I'm interested in hearing about the best practices for converting Adobe files to jpg's for an upcoming project. I've read some about Imagemagick being used to convert .psd files to jpg, but what about .ai? Is there any magic bullet solution for converting files to jpg?

My goal is to accept many image formats, but to create jpg thumbnails of these source files to display via a web interface. Is Imagemagick the best way to go or is there an easier route?

Comment: jpeg is not a good format for vector graphics such as Illustrator files. A vector format like SVG would be much truer to the original.

Comment: Good call. Do you know if Imagemagick can produce SVG files from .ai?